# Does Chromecast support TTML?

Tags: google-cast

The Chromecast developer docs say both WebVTT and TTML are Supported Media Types:
https://developers.google.com/cast/supported_media_types

I see captions when using a WebVTT file in a "track" tag within a video element:

```
<video id="vid" src="http://myurl">
    <track kind="captions" src="http://10.16.236.23/test.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default>
</video>
```

But when I try to do the same using a valid TTML file, I don't see captions:

```
<video id="vid" src="http://myurl">
    <track kind="captions" src="test.ttml" srclang="en" label="English" default>
</video>
```

When I inspect the video element in the debugger console, for the WebVTT example I can see

```
document.getElementById('vid').textTracks[0].cues.length;

16
```

but for TTML:

```
document.getElementById('vid').textTracks[0].cues.length;

0
```

I am on the right track with this or is TTML supported in a different way? Maybe my TTML syntax is not supported by Chromecast?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike webVTT, TTML is not natively supported. If you need to support that in your app, you can simply write a Javascript parser to parse the file and add the cues to your video element in javascript using methods such as addTextTrack(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cast Player API](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api#.CaptionsType), Chromecast now supports WebVTT, TTML1, and CEA-608 (Line 21 Captions) caption formats.  Just pass in the `CaptionsType` enum for your caption format into the player's [`enableCaptions()`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.Player#enableCaptions) method.